# iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network. The activity indicator spins indefinitely log in

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, app-store-connect, linkedin-api

I am trying to publish an app in itunes connect but the iOS developers tell me this:

"Guideline 2.1 - Performance

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, the activity indicator still spins indefinitely after we attempt to log in using LinkedIn.

Please see attached screenshots for details."

[linkedin sign in oauth 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUKca.png)

The thing is the webview is loaded with the linkedin URL so they can't sign in with OAuth 2.0 and linkedin user through ipv6.

Somebody know how to resolve this issue?

The app it works perfect on ipv4. Kind regards

Comment: Did you solve your problem?